# How can I find <buildId> in release build mode of Android?

Tags: android, newrelic

I am following [Manually uploading a Proguard map file](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile/getting-started/android-agent-crash-reporting#manual-proguard) doc in order to upload `mapping.txt` file to newrelic. Doc is saying:

[image]

- I know where `mapping.txt` is.
- I know Application tocken
- There is no `buildId` in the `mapping.txt` file. How can I find it?

This is the end of my `mapping.txt` file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

newrelic.propertise file must be in root of Module (not project).

Comment: Should that be `properties`?